# Where to find "MsAjaxBundle" in Asp.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-bundling

Recently I have faced an issue in my Asp.net Web application.

> The assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'MsAjaxBundle'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

It is an asp.net webforms app which runs in .NET framework 4.5

Because of this above exception, I was not able to launch my application. After clean & re-build solution my issue have got fixed.

Now I am trying to investigate the root cause for my issue. When I checked 'MsAjaxBundle' in my master page I can find the following code.

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
```

But there is no "MsAjaxBundle" implementation in BundleConfig.vb file.  Also I am unable to find any of its related implementation.

As per my research "MSAjaxBundle" loaded inside PreAppStart code. reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290537/vs2012-web-forms-bundling-confusion). Also there is no implementation inside Global.asax file.

Where I can find MSAjaxBundle implementation? or Where I can find that PreAppStart code?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i keep getting "'MsAjaxBundle' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'. " while trying to build my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698114/i-keep-getting-msajaxbundle-is-not-a-valid-script-name-the-name-must-end-in)

Comment: @DavidSdot  Thank you for the comment david. I have already gone through [Microsoft forms](https://forums.asp.net/t/1993926.aspx?Removing+Toolkit+leads+to+MsAjaxBundle+is+not+a+valid+script+name) 

Is it something to do with Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax DLL since MsAjaxBundle have no implementation?